# Use style/theme colour on a vector asset

Tags: android, material-design, android-vectordrawable, android-attributes

Hi i am trying to set a fillcolour to use the theme/style of colorOnPrimary

via  `android:fillColor="?colorOnPrimary"`

However i get this  error:  `Invalid color value ?colorOnPrimary` when i try and build my project

This is what my vector asset xml looks like:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="18dp"
    android:height="18dp"
    android:viewportWidth="18"
    android:viewportHeight="18">
    <path
        android:fillColor="?colorOnPrimary"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="...." />
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `color` use color-resources with `@color`, you might have `colorPrimary` in `colors.xml`

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="18dp"
    android:height="18dp"
    android:viewportWidth="18"
    android:viewportHeight="18">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorOnPrimary"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="...." />
</vector>
```

Comment: there was no colorPrimary but instead, a `design_default_color_on_primary`